Design the finite automata
Consider the alphabets $\sum $ ={0,1}.Design a automaton accepting the language $A=\{0^k \omega 0^k |k\geq 1 \ and \ \omega \in\sum^*\} $.
I tried to draw it. Can anyone confirm if it is correct.

Here $q_0$ is initial state and $q_{2k+1}$ is accepting state.

It's not correct. You've created a FSA that accepts$$A_k:={0^k \omega 0^k \mid \omega \in \Sigma^*}$$for some fixed, unknown $k$. The language $A$ consists of the union of these languages, over all $k \ge 1$. So, in particular, $A$ does not depend on $k$, but your FSA does. If you want a hint to proceed, try finding an alternative expression of $A$. Note, taking $A_k$ as above, that $A_1 \supseteq A_2 \supseteq \ldots$, and that $A = \bigcup_{k \ge 1} A_k$.

@TheoBendit Sir, from your hint, the automata becomes a string that start and end with 0. Am i right?

You are right!${}$

@Theo Bendit Sir can you suggest some book or pdf where i can get more of this type of question  to solve

I don't have any resources, sorry. Answering questions about automata is just a hobby of mine. You could try searching the [tag:automata] tag here, and try to answer the questions yourself before looking at the answers.
